# What should I call a class that contains a sequence of states

Tags: language-agnostic, user-interface, naming

I have a GUI tool that manages state sequences.  One component is a class that contains a set of states, your typical DFA state machine.  For now, I'll call this a `StateSet` (I have a more specific name in mind for the actual class that makes sense, but this name I think will suffice for the purpose of this question.)

However, I have another class that has a collection (possibly partially unordered) of those state sets, and lists them in a particular order. and I'm trying to come up with a good name for it - not just for internal code, but for customers to refer to it.

The role of this particular second collection is to encapsulate the entire currently used/available collection of `StateSet`s that the user has created.  All of the `StateSet`s will be used eventually in the application.  A good analogy would be a hand of cards versus the entire table: The 'table' contains all of the currently available hands, while the 'hand' contains a particular collection of cards.

I've got these as starter ideas I could throw out for the class name; I'm not comfortable with either at the moment:

- Sequence (maybe...with something else tacked on to the name)
- StateSetSet (reasonable for code, but not for customers)

And as [ewernli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554918/what-should-i-call-a-class-that-contains-a-sequence-of-states/2555533#2555533) mentions, these are really technical terms, which don't really convey a the idea well.  Any other suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the role/function of you `StateSetSet`?

- `StateSetSet` or `Sequence` are **technical** terms.
- Prefer a term that convey the **role/function** of the class.

That could well be something like `History`, `Timeline`, `WorldSnapshot`,...

**EDIT**

According to your updated description, `StateSet` looks to me like `StateSpace` (the space of all possible states). If the user can then interactively create something, it might be appropriate to speak of a `Workspace`. If the user creates various state spaces of interest, I would then go for `StateSpaceWorkspace`. Isn't that a cool name :)

Comment: Agreed.  It would be easy if I knew how to describe it...what I don't have is a good single word to describe it! :) I added a bit more to my question to see if that gives anyone else an idea.

Comment: re, your edit: yes, yes it is :)  Workspace...might be just right!

Answer (score 2):

- Sequence - Definitely **NOT**.  It's too generic, and doesn't have any real semantic meaning.
- StateSetSet - While more semantically correct, this is confusing.  You have a sequence, which implies order, which is different from a set, which does not.

That being said, the best option, IMO, is StateSetSequence, as it implies you have a sequence of StateSet instances.

Answer (score 1):

"StateSets" may be sufficient.

Others:
   StateSetList
   StateSetLister
   StateSetListing
   StateSetSequencer

Answer (score 1):

I like `StateSetArrangement`, implying an ordering without implying anything about the underlying storage mechanisms.